# How can I split a movie into sections?

Tags: itunes, video

I have a DVD that somebody recorded and burned for me, and the DVD has no chapter markers.  I ripped it to a MP4 file with Handbrake so I could put it on my iPod/iPad, but I also want it to have "chapters" like a DVD, so I can skip to the parts I want.

Is there an easy way to do this?  I didn't see an option in Handbrake (it seems to be ripping only), or in iTunes.  Can iMovie help me here?  Is there a cheaper/easier way?

It doesn't have to be exact, or terribly easy to use.  I'm perfectly willing to just provide a list of MM:SS points (there's only 4 or 5).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it personally, but it looks like [Subler](https://code.google.com/p/subler/) will do what you want.

Here is the proper format you need to use for the chapter file: https://code.google.com/p/subler/wiki/ChapterTextFormat

> Subler will allow you to add chapters. You just need to drag and drop a
>   text file in the right format into Subler. You don't write them in in
>   the Subler GUI.
>
> The Subler site explains the format. It took a lot of trial and error
>   for me to get it right and it is time consuming so I haven't done it
>   in a while. Otherwise, I'd tell you how I did it.
>
> Once you add the file, you will have a new row under the Video Track
>   and Stereo rows called Chapter Track. You can edit the Titles in there
>   if you want to, but if you created the file correctly, you shouldn't
>   have to.

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=901354